# getting 404 when trying to add songs to using spotify api

Tags: python, api, python-requests, spotify

I'm making a project which will add songs from your youtube playlist to spotify playlist. everything works fine except the `add_item()` method. I'm getting `404 : not found` response from the `requests` object.

Yes, i checked if the song actually exists. It does and even printed the `id` of the song.So it exists.

[I'm following the official documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/add-tracks-to-playlist/)

here is my code -

```
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import requests
import base64
import  urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs



client_id = #id
client_secret = #secret
redirect_uri = 'https://www.spotify.com'
scope = "playlist-modify-public user-read-email user-read-private playlist-modify-private"
req = f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'
encoded = base64.b64encode(req.encode())

class sp :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.get_token()
        self.get_id()
        self.uri_list = []


    def get_token(self) :
        url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
        oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri = redirect_uri, scope = scope)
        authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(url)
        print(authorization_url)
        authorization_response = input('paste here : ')

        parsed = urlparse.urlparse(authorization_response)
        authorization_code = parse_qs(parsed.query)['code'][0]

        # to get auth token
        headers = {
            'Authorization' : f'Basic {encoded.decode()}'
        }
        data = {
            'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' : redirect_uri,
            'code' : authorization_code
        }

        access = requests.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data = data, headers = headers)
        response = json.loads(access.text)
        self.access_token = response['access_token']

    def get_id(self) :
        headers = {
            'Authorization' : f'Bearer {self.access_token}'
        }
        user_info = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', headers = headers)
        user_info.raise_for_status()
 

        user_info = json.loads(user_info.text)
        self.user_id  = user_info['id']

    def search(self) :
        
        search_url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search'

        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.access_token}'
        }
        params = {
            'q' : 'track:Memories artist:Maroon 5', 
            'type' : 'track',
            'limit' : 1,

        }

        search_response = requests.get(search_url, headers = headers, params = params)
        search_response.raise_for_status()
        
        json_response = search_response.json()
        song_uri =  json_response['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
        self.uri_list.append(song_uri)
        
    def create_playlist(self) :
        create_playlist_url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{self.user_id}/playlists'

        headers = {
            'Authorization' : f'Bearer {self.access_token}',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }

        data = json.dumps({
            'name' : 'new playlist'
        })
        response = requests.post(create_playlist_url, headers = headers, data = data)
        print(response)
        self.playlist_id = response.json()['uri']

    def add_items(self) :
        add_items_url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{self.playlist_id}/tracks'

        headers = {
            'Authorization' : f'Bearer {self.access_token}',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
        print(self.uri_list)
        data = {
            'uris' : json.dumps(self.uri_list)
        }

        res = requests.post(add_items_url, headers = headers, data = data)
        print(res)





user = sp()

user.create_playlist()
user.search()
user.add_items()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line of code for playlist creation:

```py
self.playlist_id = response.json()['uri']
```

and then in items addition logic you have:

```py
add_items_url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{self.playlist_id}/tracks'
```

are you sure that you want to use playlist uri as playlist id?

Could you update your question with more info:

1. `response.json()` value after playlist is created
2. print `add_items_url` after f-string was declared

---

**UPDATE**

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/ as I can see here - the response after creation of the playlist include `id` field

So you should just change this line

```py
self.playlist_id = response.json()['uri']
```

to

```py
self.playlist_id = response.json()['id']
```

Comment: hey, thanks for reply. I changed `uri` to `id` (careless mistake ik :) ).But still im getting `400` as error which stands for bad syntax

Comment: on `add_items` step?

Comment: yes, but any way i found out the syntax error which i was supposed to convert the whole data dict to a json string. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Yw! Lmk if you need more help with that spotify code. :)